# IF function and Cycle

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding excel vba and the use of the "IF" function with the "For" cycle. I will try to be as clear as possible.

here is the code:

```
sub cicleFor()
For i= 1 to 2
Calculate
Range("E3").Select
Selection.Copy    Sheets("Sheet2").Select    Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C14").Select
Next
```

It is pretty simple! I take E3, copy paste into another cell (A2) for two times.
I use calculate at the start because the number in E3 will change each time

What I would like to have is the following:

to use an "IF" function that, if A2 is full, goes to A3 and so on, for i = 1 to 100.

since I have used a for function, i want A2,A3,A4,...A100 to be filled with the result of E3 of the sheet1.

I am not an expert as you can see!

if you have any hint, I will be grateful!

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to make calculations manual, and only calculate *after* the loop completed. Or, if you need a specific cell calculated, qualify that `Calculate` call with a `Range` object. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just populate the cells with the formula `=Sheet1!$E$3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** to add the case of multiple cells

maybe you're after this

```
Sub cicleFor()
    For i = 1 To 100
        Calculate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

if you need to copy/paste the content of more than one cell then you want to use `Resize(nRows, nColumns)` property of `Range` object to properly adjust the "target" range size to fit the "source" one

for instance to copy/paste the content of range "E3:H3" (i.e. four columns) you want to use:

```
Sub cicleFor()
    For i = 1 To 100
        Calculate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, 1).Resize(,4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:H3").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! this is what I wanted! only one thing: what if, instead of copying only "E3", I want to copy a line (e.g. "F3:H3")??

Comment: @StevenIngo, you are welcome. So which answer did actually solve your question? Mine, or Tim Williams' one?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be much shorter - no need for select/copy/paste if you only want to transfer the values.  Use `End(xlUp)` to locate the last used cell.

```
Sub cicleFor()

    For i= 1 to 2
        Calculate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
              Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You've landed in the LQ queue... No explanation or anything?

Comment: thank you! this is what I wanted as above! only one thing: what if, instead of copying only "E3", I want to copy a line (e.g. "F3:H3")??